# Should I Calculate Time Values or Declare Them At The Start of My Code?

Tags: datetime, optimization, time, micro-optimization

TL;DR: Whats better?

```
cookie_expires = time()+( (60*60*24)*31 )
```

vs.

```
cookie_expires = SECONDS_month
```

To save time and typing, for years I have been declaring useful time values at the start of my apps.

```
SECONDS_hour = 3600
SECONDS_day = 86400
SECONDS_week = 604800
SECONDS_month = 2678400
SECONDS_year = 31557600
```

I was wondering what the gurus here think. Should I not waste the effort and just calculate as needed?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs at [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion readability always goes first:

"one_week_in_seconds" is way better than 60*60*24*7!